# Help Find (or Create) a CW Resources List

Tags: discussion, online-resources, resource-request

I could have sworn we had a CW meta post that listed references useful to English learners; dictionaries, sites like lang-8, grammar references, etc. Since resource requests are off topic, this post was useful to link as a reference when such questions were asked on the main site.

I tried to find it today, though, and was unsuccessful. (I think this happened to be once before as well.) So, does anyone out there with better search capabilities than me know where I can find it? Alternatively, if I'm wrong and there never was any such post (I know for sure we *talked* about one) then we should create it. So let's start building up some resources as answers to this question, and we can move all of them into a CW post later on if the old one isn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/resources-for-learning-english. I looked at the questions tagged [resources](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), and found it.

Comment: Thank you!! I swear I searched for this thing, but I couldn't find it. Now I've favorited it, so this won't happen again ;)  Thanks so much!

Comment: *Oh*, and I just figured out why I couldn't find it. I was searching meta, and the post is on the main site. I'll move it to meta and tag it [faq] so it can be found more easily in the future :)

Comment: It does no harm to have this question here. When others are looking for the CW resources list, they might well get there via this answer.

Comment: @WendiKidd I would move it on meta. That is what I did on Drupal Answer: I created a [meta-tag:faq] question about Drupal resources/tutorials.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I tried too but it's too old to migrate ;) I've poked Shog and he's going to move it for us :)